# How to mock the linq expression in c#

Tags: c#, moq

I am writing the unit test of linq expression using moq

my linq expression getting employee list based on condition like employeeid and active record.

This is my linq expression

```
employeess.Get(x => x.EmployeeId == employeeId && x.Active == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

i have set up the below generic expression to mock the employee list.

```
mockrepo.Setup(x => 
  x.Get(
    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Employee, bool>>>(), 
    It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<Employee>, 
    IOrderedQueryable<Employee>>>(), 
    It.IsAny<string>()
    )
).Returns(employeeList.AsQueryable());
```

i want to write unit test to get the employeelist based on condition. how to mock the linq expression with condition

Comment: Why you need to mock it.

Comment: We write unit tests for methods, not a statement inside a method.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend a little redesign, if it is possible: You should remove your predicate parameter on Get, because, as you are returning an IQueryable, one is able to define conditions like "only get active records " later on.

Instead of

```
employeess.Get(x => x.EmployeeId == employeeId && x.Active == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

your code would become

```
employees.Get().FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeID == employeeId && Active == 1);
```

It now gets way easier to mock Get() as you just need to return employeeList.AsQuerable().

Answer (score 0):

Moq does not supports with Expression function so here is the best solution. Use this nuget package [Moq.Expression](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoqExpression/)

```
// import namespace
using MoqExpression;

// you should do like this it will work
mockrepo.Setup(x => x.SearchFor(MoqHelper.IsExpression<Employee>(s => s.Name.Equals("Test")))).Returns(employeeList.AsQueryable());
```

For more documentation: [click here](https://github.com/ovaishanif94/Moq.Expression)

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. Use in-memory ORM (if one is used for Active Record) or in-memory collection of objects.
2. Expose Active Record class as Active Record interface, mock interface methods and supply mocked interface to class where it is used.

Usually expressions are never mocked, since they are part of business logic. Mainly recommendations for mocking are based on application architecture.